# How to handle "ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337)"?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to import a environment to my anaconda and then I get a error like this:

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::openssl-1.0.2k-1'.

UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '/Users/fengxinlin/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.9/bin:/Users/fengxinlin/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin}\xc2\xa0', 236, 237, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
Attempting to roll back.

It looks like a decoding issue, but what can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved this problem somehow. I completely removed anaconda2 and downloaded anaconda3, then re-import env file, I never got this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found this resource, and hopefully it'll help.  Have any non-ASCII characters in your path?
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5432

Best of luck!

Comment: You should provide the actual answer here as well and not just a link

Comment: Thanks for your answering, that issue was also posted by me :)

Comment: Oh, that's too funny!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exact same error, I've deleted all files linked to conda under folder C:\Users{user} and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got this on Linux OS and was missing the openssl package or some of its commands.